# Select top 10 events from wevtutil using xpath

Tags: xpath

I am currently working on a project that uses the Windows event log. I am using `wevtutil` to get the results from the event logs. I know that `wevtutil` supports xpath queries, but since I'm new to xpath I don't know that I can achieve what I'm trying to do.

In SQL, what I would be doing is something like this:

```
SELECT log.*, COUNT(1) numHits
FROM Application log
GROUP BY Source, Task, Level, Description
ORDER BY numHits DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Is it possible to do such a thing using xpath?

**Edit:** Here is a sample Event:

```
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>

  <System>
    <Provider Name='MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS' />
    <EventID Qualifiers='16384'>17403</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>2</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime='2010-10-20T20:06:18.000Z' />
    <EventRecordID>9448</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>SHAZTOP</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>73094</Data>
    <Binary>
    FB4300000A000000130000005300480041005A0054004F0050005C00530051004C004500580050005200450053005300000000000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two short and complete XPath and XSLT solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath 1.0 has four data types: string, number, boolean and node set.

The only XPath ordering criteria is document order (in the given axis direction). That is how you can limit any result node set as @Dimitre and @Welbog have sugested with `fn:position()`.

But, there is no specification that an XPath engine must provide a node set result in any given order. So, you can't sort nor grouping in XPath 1.0. You can select the firsts of each group, but not efficiently. As example:

```
//Event[not(System/Level = preceding::Level) or 
        not(System/Task = preceding::Task)]
```

XPath 2.0 has the sequence data type. A sequence has the exclicit order of construction. So, you can group. As example:

```
for $event (//Event)[index-of(//Event/System/concat(Level,'++',Task),
                              System/concat(Level,'++',Task))[1]]
result //Event[System/Level = $event/System/Level]
              [System/Task = $event/System/Task]
```

But, because XPath 2.0 has not built-in sorting nor recursion mechanism (you could provide an extension function...) you can't sort.

For that you need a language with built-in sorting or a way to express its algorithm. Both XSLT (1.0 or 2.0) and XQuery have these features.

Comment: You are wrong about XPath 2.0 . It can sort. Proof: http://www.ximeco.org/Xime/XPathCanSortHlousek.pdf . In XPath 3.0 it becomes simple and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

> In SQL, what I would be doing is
>   something like this:
>
> ```
> SELECT log.*, COUNT(1) numHits 
> FROM Application log 
> GROUP BY Source, Task, Level, Description 
> ORDER BY numHits DESC 
> LIMIT 10
> ```
>
> Is it possible to do such a thing
>   using xpath?

**In case no sorting is necessary, one can get the first `$n` nodes selected by any XPath expression by**:

```
(ExpressionSelectingNodeSet)[not(position() > $n)]
```

where `$n` can be substituted by a specific number

**If there is a requirement that the nodes be sorted on one or more sort-keys, then this is not possible pure XPath, but one can easily perform such tasks with XSLT, using the [`<xsl:sort>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#element-sort) instruction and the XPath [`position()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-position) function**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <nums>
   <xsl:for-each select="num">
    <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="descending"/>
     <xsl:if test="not(position() > 5)">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </nums>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>010</num>
</nums>
```

**the correct result, containing only the top 5 numbers is produced**:

```
<nums>
    <num>010</num>
    <num>09</num>
    <num>08</num>
    <num>07</num>
    <num>06</num>
</nums>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`position()`](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#context) function to limit the results you're getting:

```
/root/element[position()<=10]
```

For example, that would select the first ten `element` elements which are children of the root.

If your structure is more complicated, you can use the position element in different places. For example, if the `element` element can exist in more than one parent, but you want the first ten of them regardless of parent, you can do it this way:

```
(/root/parent1/element | /root/parent2/element)[position()<=10]
```

Comment: That sort of helps. How would I do the grouping though? I'll edit the original post to share a sample Event.

Comment: XPath doesn't have grouping built into it.